# PHP: все ли части обрабатываются в составном логическом выражении или обработка прекращается после первого false?

Tags: php

Допустим, в выражении

```
if (0 == 1 && (2+2) == 5 && $object->getValue() == true) { ... }
```

Будет ли высчитываться 2+2 и $object->getValue() или логическое выражение сразу вернет ложь из-за 0 == 1 ?

Comment: Сразу вернет ложь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такое понятие, как [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (оно же minimal evaluation, оно же McCarthy evaluation).

Суть Short-circuit evaluation состоит в том, что для логических выражений, использующих определенные логические операторы (в русской документации оно переведено, как ["шунтирующие операторы"](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php)), вычисление результата всего выражения происходит последовательно, слева направо и прекращается тогда, когда вычисление последующих частей выражения не повлияет на конечный результат.

Например

```
$a = false && expression2 && expression3 && ....;
$b = false || true || expression2 || expression3 || ....;
```

Вычисление значения для `$a` остановится сразу же после первого `false`. `expression2` и `expression3` даже не будут вычисляться/исполняться, поскольку уже не смогут повлиять на конечный результат.

Вычисление `$b` остановится после первого выражения, вернувшего `true`, по тем же причинам.

В PHP, шунтирующими операторами(т.е. для которых будет выполняться подобный алгоритм вычисления) являются `&&`, `||`, `and` и `or`

Answer (score 2):

```
function test() {
    echo 'Hello!';
}

if (0 == 1 && test() && (2+2) == 5 && $object->getValue() == true) { 
    //
}
```

в результате "Hello" выведено не будет. Из чего можно сделать какое-то предположение...

Comment: ......хейтеры))

Comment: Уж извини. Тут про short-circuit evaluation рассказывать надо, а не мистику разводить. Расскажешь, или я сам?

Comment: .....комьюнити))

Comment: @rjhdby каждый пишет ответ как тот считает нужным